# Python 2.6 dictionary builder notation

Tags: python, python-2.7, tuples, python-2.6

I have 2 lists `'a','b','c'` and `1,2,3` and I zip them together to get a dict `{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}`. I did the following successfully on Python 2.7:

```
fields = ['a', 'b', 'c']
values = [1, 2, 3]
record = {key:value for key,value in zip(fields, values)}
```

But on Python 2.6.6, it gives me syntax error at the `for` on line 3.

Is it that the dictionary-builder notation is not supported in Python 2.6.6 ?

And if so, what is the alternative method of achieving the dict `{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}` efficently?

Comment: It's a dict comprehension which has been added in Python 2.7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are trying to do is a *dictionary comprehension* which is not available in your version of python.

You can generate your dict from (key,value) tuples:

```
>>> dict((key,value) for key,value in zip(fields,values))
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

*edit*

excellent comment by @PeterWood:

Use `dict(zip(fields, values))`. This is shorter and faster.

```
In [15]: timeit dict((key,value) for key,value in zip(range(1000),range(1000)))
1000 loops, best of 3: 317 µs per loop
In [16]: timeit dict(zip(range(1000), range(1000)))
10000 loops, best of 3: 138 µs per loop
```

With `itertools.izip` you get another performance boost:

```
In [25]: timeit dict((key,value) for key,value in izip(range(1000),range(1000)))
1000 loops, best of 3: 286 µs per loop
In [24]: timeit dict(izip(range(1000), range(1000)))
10000 loops, best of 3: 78.6 µs per loop
```

Comment: Why not `dict(zip(fields, values))`?

Comment: Well because I did not see that. Mind if edit it in?

Comment: Which one is more efficient ? I am going to use it over *huge* data

Comment: I did some quick tests with `timeit`, `dict(zip(fields, values))` seems to be a bit faster (which makes sense).

Comment: @davneet I don't know about efficiency, and wouldn't worry. The other solution uses a generator expression which is likely to be efficient. However, you can use [**`timeit`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) to see. `zip` would be the place to improve efficiency by using [**`izip`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) instead.

Comment: Cool, using izip finally.